# Custom Domain in IBM Bluemix

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

How to add our own domain? Do we need to setup any environment like Node?There is an automated domain generated but I want the web app to run my personal domain.

Comment: check this http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/bluemix-ui-ssl-certificates-and-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

After you've configured the custom domain in Bluemix, you must map the custom domain to the Bluemix system domain on your registered DNS server:

Set up a 'CNAME' record for the custom domain name on your DNS server\domain host.

Map the custom domain name to the secure endpoint for the Bluemix region where your application is running. Use the following region endpoints to provide the URL route that is allocated to your organization in Bluemix:

- US-SOUTH: secure.us-south.bluemix.net
- EU-GB: secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
- AU-SYD: secure.au-syd.bluemix.net

more information here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/secapps.html and here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html